# Licensing open-source code and art assets

Tags: licensing

I want to build a permissively-licensed web site, but preserve copyright for art assets included in the repo.

How do open software licenses differentiate between code and art assets/content? Recognizing that all licenses are different, are there any useful general guidelines for what is and isn't covered by a software license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Licenses aren't all-or-nothing. However, its useful to keep material under different licenses clearly separate. For example, your web site might have multiple directories: `backend`, `js`, `assets`, `content`. You could then clarify that different licenses apply to different parts:

`LICENSE.txt`:

> Some Pretty Website
> Copyright 2021 Some Person
>
> The material in `backend/` and `js/` is licensed under the MIT license, see `LICENSE.MIT.txt`.
>
> The material in `assets/` is licensed under the [CC-BY-NC-ND license 4.0](https://www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/), with the exception of the following assets:
>
> - `assets/stock-photo.jpg`: public domain image from [Some Website](https://example.com).
> - `assets/wikipedia.png`: [Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg) by Nohat (CC-BY-SA 3.0 license).
>
> The material in `content/` is all rights reserved, and included for reference only.

In textual files, it might be possible to clarify the file's license with a [machine-readable SPDX-License-Identifier comment](https://spdx.dev/ids/).

In many cases, it will be less confusing to have different repositories for parts under different licenses. If there's only one applicable license, automated tools (like the auto-detected repository license field on GitHub) will be more accurate.

Note that in any case, you do retain your copyright. Open-source licenses work *because* you have a copyright: you as the copyright holder give certain permissions to the public. You are not bound by your licenses yourself. E.g. you can give a copy of your code to one person under the GPL license, another copy to someone else under the MIT license, and even sell a proprietary non-exclusive license to a another party.